# Converting str to float in pandas warning

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert str to float in a pandas data frame and get the following error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

The code:

```
df_clean['a'] = df_clean['a'].astype(float)
```

Should I ignore it? Can it be written without generating the warning?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=A+value+is+trying+to+be+set+on+a+copy+of+a+slice+from+a+DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df_clean['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df_clean['a'], errors='ignore')
```

The "errors" flag gives you different options for how to handle ones that cannot be converted.